# I can not find Card-columns class in my bootstrap..how can i make Masonry-like effect?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can not find the card-columns class in my bootstrap.
I have to make a picture galery in Masonry-like effect.
I am using asp.net .How can i do it.??

Comment: you can use this external library --> https://github.com/desandro/masonry

Comment: Which version of bootstrap?